# flask url conflicting with href

Tags: flask, jinja2

In my HTML code i have the following jinja template code:

```
{% for site in sites %}
    <a href="{{ site.site_link }}">{{ site.site_name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The issue is: let's assume that `{{ site.site_link }} = www.domainname.com`, so whenever the link is clicked it supposed to direct the user to the domainname page. but, it leads to :

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/www.domainname.com

which is a 404..Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?
I don't know if this is relevant, but, I am using flask Blueprints.

Comment: you just missed the http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put http:// in front of it, like href="http://........"

```
{% for site in sites %}
    <a href="http://{{ site.site_link }}">{{ site.site_name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: who would've thought?!!, Thank you :)